# Why someObject = Object.assign({}, someObject, window.getSelection()) and {...window.getSelection()} does return empty object?

Tags: javascript

I try to copy `window.getSelection()` to `someObject` to store it as an object property for future reusing.

I have this code:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();

//case 1:
this.selection = Object.assign({}, this.selection, selection);

console.log(this.selection);
console.log(selection);

//---------------------------------------

//case 2:
this.selection = {...window.getSelection()};

console.log(this.selection);
console.log(selection);
```

In both cases (case 1 and case 2) I see in console empty object `{}` for `this.selection` and Selection object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) for `selection` variable.

What have I missed? How to copy window.getSelection() to `this.selection` (which is a class property)?

Comment: You probably need a custom thing where you go through each property and copy their values. The object that `getSelection()` returns derives stuff from its prototype, hence why you get an empty object when you try to clone it.

Comment: `The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all *enumerable own properties*` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object/assign)

Comment: @VLAZ , should I use for-in?

Comment: @epascarello, I thought properties from MDN, marked as "Read only" is own properties of "Selection" object.

Comment: You can use this class as example for save selection: https://gist.github.com/dantaex/543e721be845c18d2f92652c0ebe06aa

Comment: @DenisStukalov, I need save caret position and modify it in some cases which means I need copy `window.getSelection()` and modify it in the future. Thank you for your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript uses a prototype chain. When you try to access a property in an object, the JS engine checks for that property in the object, then in the object's prototype, then in the object's prototype's prototype, etc...

Properties directly present in the object are called *own properties*. The `selection` object has no own properties, instead, properties like `anchorNode` are defined as getters **in the prototype**.

You can see this in the developer console. It shows properties directly in the object, but that's just for readability. They are really in the object's prototype.

[image: console showing prototype chain]

Both [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) only copy **own** enumerable properties, it won't work in this case.

Comment: Thank you! So what is the alternative?

Comment: It depends. Why do you want to clone the object?

Comment: I want to copy those 8 properties which I thought was own properties because of console screenshot? I need to modify some of them and restore selection later.

Comment: At current moment I need only 5 of them: anchorNode, anchorOffset, focusNode, focusOffset and isCollapsed.

Comment: Using `for(var prop in selection){` return object with properties and methods of `window.getSelection()`. I don't need methods to copy and not sure if that is the best way in my case.

Comment: Wait, so you are trying to restore a selection by setting the properties on the object? It wouldn't work, because the properties only have getters, not setters.

Comment: Yes, that is why I want to copy/clone them to have ability to modify them in the future.

Comment: You can try to do it manually (`{anchorNode: selection.anchorNode, anchorOffset: selection.anchorOffset, ...}`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save Selection for further use, you can restore Selection from the Range object like this:

```
// Save Range from the current Selection
let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

/* Suppose here the Selection object has changed */

// Restore previous Selection
const selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```